# Angular 16 - 3rd party script not loading in time?

Tags: angular, momentjs

We've been using `moment.js` in our app for years at this point, we add it via the `scripts` property in our `angular.json` file.

Note the definition for the scripts property:

> An object containing JavaScript script files to add to the global context of the project. The scripts are loaded exactly as if you had added them in a  tag inside index.html. See more in the Styles and scripts configuration section.

After the upgrade from 15 -> 16 now when our app loads, one of the first components to load references moment and we get
`global-error-handler-local.ts:32 ERROR ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

in our `scripts` property we have it simply defined as:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
],
```

If I inspect the `scripts.js` file that was generated and included I can see that moment is inside, so I'm not sure what's causing it to be unavailable when the app loads.

Again, this has been working fine for years. In messing around trying to figure out what's going on, I did notice that if I change it from the simple style to:

```
"scripts": [
  { 
    "input": "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "moment"
  },
],
```

and then edit our `index.html` to include the bundle

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="moment.js"></script>
</head>
```

it's back to working fine again.

We obviously have more scripts than just moment otherwise I probably wouldn't bother continuing to dig into this. But does anyone know what changed in v16 that's causing the simple approach to no longer work?